# Magento 2.2 adminside products edit getting error

Tags: magento2.2, data-migration

After Data migration from Magento 1.9.1.1 to 2.2  admin side products edit getting the error.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/new/vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Helper/Minsaleqty.php on line 203
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that in my case it's related to a module that was installed before the migration that doesn't work after the fact.

As a workaround, you can edit the file mentioned above,. and insert the following before the foreach() on line 203.

if( !is_array( $value ) ){ return false; }

This allows me to edit products once again. In my case it was to do with an affiliate plugin that was set to use special pricing.